# Exclude certain fields during serialization using play-json-extensions

Tags: scala, play-json

I have a case class that is having more than 22 parameters and to serialize this case class I am using json-play-extension.

Pseudo code is as follows

```
case class Foo(a1: Int,a2: Int,a3: Int,...,a24: Int)
```

I have an implicit for Foo as follows

```
implicit val jsonFormat : OFormat[Foo] = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[Foo]
```

Till now, my only requirement was to simply serialize and deserialize this case class. However, now I have an additional requirement to exclude certain fields during serialization. For example, in my output I want to exclude fields a1 and a2 from the json output.

My desired output is as follows

```
{
“a3” : 3,
“a4” : 4,
.
.
“a24” : 24
}
```

Please let me know if there are any extension method that will allow me to perform such activity. Any pointers will be highly helpful. 
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [pruning](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaJsonTransformers#Case-6:-Prune-a-branch-from-input-JSON) multiple JSON branches by [andThen](https://coderwall.com/p/ui276q/prune-multiple-json-branches-with-play-json) composition:

```
(__ \ "a1" ).json.prune andThen (__ \ "a2" ).json.prune
```

Here is a working example

```
import ai.x.play.json.Jsonx
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Foo(a1: Int, a2: Int, a3: Int, a4: Int, a5: Int, a6: Int, a7: Int, a8: Int, a9: Int, a10: Int, a11: Int, a12: Int, a13: Int, a14: Int, a15: Int, a16: Int, a17: Int, a18: Int, a19: Int, a20: Int, a21: Int, a22: Int, a23: Int, a24: Int)

object Foo {
  implicit val format = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[Foo]
}

object ExcludeFieldsFromSerialisation extends App {
  val pruneTransformation = (field: String) => (__ \ field).json.prune
  val excludedFields = List("a1", "a2").map(pruneTransformation).reduce((prune1, prune2) => prune1 andThen prune2)
  val json = Json.toJson(Foo(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24))
  val prunedJson = json.transform(excludedFields)
  println(prunedJson.get)
}
```

which should output

```
{
    "a2": 2,
    "a3": 3,
    "a4": 4,
    "a5": 5,
    "a6": 6,
    "a7": 7,
    "a8": 8,
    "a9": 9
    "a10": 10,
    "a11": 11,
    "a12": 12,
    "a13": 13,
    "a14": 14,
    "a15": 15,
    "a16": 16,
    "a17": 16,
    "a18": 18,
    "a19": 19,
    "a20": 20,
    "a21": 21,
    "a22": 22,
    "a23": 23,
    "a24": 24,
}
```